# Error saving picture to file system (Works on Emulator; Fails on device)

Tags: android, filesystems

Have a simple app that works fine on the emulator but not on my phone. Singe activity with a button. On pressing the button the camera starts and the picture is saved in the file system under Pictures. Have a toast which displays the path where the picture is stored.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==0){
        switch (resultCode){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                if(imagefile.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"The picture is stored here  " + imagefile.getAbsolutePath() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error storing the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;


            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
```

The toast on the emulator shows the path. However I get the error toast on the phone. I have the permissions for External storage read/write. And here is the value of my file

```
imagefile= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"test.jpg");
    Uri tempUri= Uri.fromFile(imagefile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,tempUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: what is the error you see on toast?

Comment: Maybe phrased that wrong. It goes into the else block above and returns the above comment. With the emulator it returns the file path in the first toast.

Comment: also share how you set the value of `imagefile`

Comment: 'imagefile= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"test.jpg");
        Uri tempUri= Uri.fromFile(imagefile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,tempUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);'

Comment: Check if `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` is getting you the right path (probably put it in a string and Log it to check. And then verify if the `test.jpg` is really present in the given path.